Problem with sending String to captive Portal on Arduino
I've got this code:
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include "gateway.h"
#include <HTTPClient.h>

// Variables for Server
const byte DNS_PORT = 53;
IPAddress apIP(8, 8, 4, 4); // The default android DNS
DNSServer dnsServer;
WiFiServer server(80);

int counter=0;

String currentIP = "192.168.0.100";

String responseHTML = getHTML();

const char *serialNum;
const char *ipAddr;

String sNumForHTML = "";
String ipForHTML = "";
int incomingByte = 0;


// Function for starting server
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting AP and connecting to WiFi network");

  // Start AP mode
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  WiFi.softAP("Gateway_server");
  WiFi.softAPConfig(apIP, apIP, IPAddress(255, 255, 255, 0));

  // Start DNS Server
  dnsServer.start(DNS_PORT, "*", apIP);
  

  // Start web server
  server.begin();
}

// Function which get cast one time of each frame
void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read the incoming byte:
    String value = Serial.readString();
    Serial.print("incoming Value: ");
    Serial.println(value); 
  }
  dnsServer.processNextRequest();
  WiFiClient client = server.available(); // listen for incoming clients
  if (client) {
  // send data only when you receive data:
    String currentLine = "";
    while (client.connected()) {
      if (client.available()) {
        char c = client.read();
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (currentLine.length() == 0) {
            client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            client.println("Content-type:text/html");
            client.println();
            client.print(responseHTML);
            break;
          } else {
            currentLine = "";
          }
        } else if (c != '\r') {
          currentLine += c;
        }
      }
    }
    client.stop();
  }
}

It creates a Captive Portal-Server on my ESP32 how can i send Data (like a IP-String) which i insert in a textfield on the captive portal webview (Response HTML) to this arduino code to manage it?
I know how i can get the input of a text field in HTML using JS but how can i send it to the ardunio code which upload the webview?
Or is it even possible?
THX for helping.
I tried to solve this problem using serial or http requests but it didn't work.

Google "esp32 captive portal", there are plenty of tutorial. In short, whatever the "webview" the Arduino serves to a client is a HTML page, so the handling of sending data back is exactly like a webpage (using JS), the Arduino needs to have a route to intercept the request and send the response back.
